# why Android Webview sometimes does not display anything?

Tags: java, android, caching, webview, custom-component

I need to open a PDF file from URL like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_tutorial.pdf)

So I'm using Webview, but sometimes (most of the time) does not display anything.

Here is my code:

```
        Url = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_tutorial.pdf";

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                progDailog.show();
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                progDailog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(Url);
```

---

Shat should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the onReceivedError method in your WebViewClient to handle errors.

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    // Handle error
    Log.e("WebViewError", "Error: " + description);
}
```

You can also try to use Google Docs Viewer directly.

Url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_tutorial.pdf";

Comment: Thank u so much for the answer. I used  onReceivedError, but there was no Error! I Know shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not called and  onPageFinished is called! finally I had to use "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="  instead of WebView